# sql sum group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to score gaming tournaments. There are multiple tournaments and each team has two players, player1 and player2. When signing up either player could be in player1 or Player2 position. I need to sum up the points earned across tournament whenever the same two player are teamed together.

```
Tournament_ID|Player1|Player2|Points
------------------------------------
1            |Smith  |Green  |8
1            |Brown  |Peck   |3
1            |Jones  |Healy  |2

2            |Smith  |Green  |5
2            |Peck   |Brown  |3
2            |Jones  |Healy  |1

3            |Healy  |Jones  |9
3            |Smith  |Green  |5
3            |Peck   |Brown  |3
```

Results should look like:

```
Place  Team              Total Points
1      Smith & Green        18
2      Jones & Healy        12
3      Brown & Peck          9
```

Comment: What had been the Place results if also Jones & Healy had 18 points?

Comment: What have you tried so far? it seems you know what you're after here, a `GROUP BY`, so why did what you tried not work?

Comment: If using a `Group BY` this will work unless the players were entered as 'Green and Smith'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Player1 < Player2 THEN Player1 ELSE Player2 END AS Player1,
        CASE WHEN Player1 < Player2 THEN Player2 ELSE Player1 END AS Player2,
        Points
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC) Place,
    Player1 + ' & ' + Player2,
    SUM(Points) AS [Total Points]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Player1 + ' & ' + Player2;
```

[image]

### Demo